# How Do I Make an Object Look Two-Dimensional, But Have The Rest of My Project 3D?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have recently had an idea of having a three-dimensional background and landscape, but all the people to look two-dimensional. I know you can enable freestyle rendering, but that affects everything and doesn't have the right look. I want to make something like the Disney short, ***Paperman***. They used 3D software but made everything look drawn. I want to do this but only on a few objects. I am currently in the planning process, so I don't have any .blend files or images. I hope this is enough information. Let me know if you need any more details! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into using render layers and combine with Z depth, and that way you can set up freestyle ONLY on the layers that have the characters then.